# Having 8-bit and 16-bit views on the same data?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, buffer, 8-bit

## Problem

I'm working on a video game emulator using C++.

The memory is represented by an array of uint8_t values. Often, I also need to access the contents of this memory as 16-bit values (two consecutive 8-bit values).

I have something that looks like this:

```
struct Memory {

  uint8_t map[0xFFFF];

  // Let's say that [] is for accessing 8-bit values
  uint8_t& operator[](uint16_t address) {
      return map[address];
  }

 // () is for 16-bit values
  uint16_t& operator()(uint16_t address) {
      return ???; // Looking for a good implementation here
  }
};
```

For instance, if the memory contains [0xC0, 0xFF, 0x66, 0xAA...] then `[]` would  return:

`mem[0] -> 0xC0`
`mem[1] -> 0xFF`
`mem[2] -> 0x66`

and `()` would return (depending on the system endianness):

`mem(0) -> 0xFFC0`
`mem(1) -> 0x66FF`
`mem(2) -> 0xAA66`

Those access methods are going to get called *a lot*. I would like to leverage pointers in `()` for fast access. I don't want to compute 16-bit values by shifting and |'ing 8-bit pairs (and I cannot as the method must return a reference).

**My question:** Is there a way in C++ to have different *views* on the same buffer? A 8-bit view and a 16-bit view pointing at the same data would be ideal.

(For example, the [JS ArrayBuffer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) provides DataView, which can do just that. Maybe there is a clever trick to achieve that cleanly with pointers in C++?)

## Attempt #1

My first guess was to use some sort of union:

```
union mem_t {
    uint8_t bytes[0xFFFF];
    uint16_t words[0x8000]
}
```

But then only 16-bit values at even bytes can be accessed:

`mem.words[0] -> 0xFFC0`

`mem.words[1] -> 0xAA66 // Should be 0x66FF :(`

## Attempt #2

A working solution is to have two additional 16-bit pointers for even and odd addresses, to handle *overlapping*:

```
uint16_t* even16 = (uint16_t*) map;
uint16_t* odd16 = (uint16_t*) (map + 1);

uint16_t& Memory::operator()(uint16_t address) {
    return address % 2 ? odd16[address / 2] : even16[address / 2];
}
```

It works fine but it seems very convoluted and I'm sure there are more elegant solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `return *(uint16_t*)&map[address];` ? You are making it way too complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Igor, this works fine. However, I'm still interested in a "lazier" approach without a cast at each access.

Comment: Then cast it one time and save it into a pointer...

Comment: You make it sound as if you've measured performance and determined that the cast is a performance bottleneck. Which would be highly unlikely as the cast is usually purely for the benefit of the compiler - it doesn't correspond to any actual machine code executed at run time.

Comment: Igor: Thanks for claryfiyng this. I'll go with your approach. deviantfan: such a cached pointer cannot access 16-bit data starting at all addresses (only those with the same parity as the address of the first access would be acessible, with an offset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this, but you may fall foul of memory alignment rules on your host system:

```
struct Memory {

    uint8_t map[0xFFFF];

    // Let's say that [] is for accessing 8-bit values
    uint8_t& operator[](uint16_t address) {
        return map[address];
    }

    // () is for 16-bit values
    uint16_t& operator()(uint16_t address) {
        return *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&map[address]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. How does this reinterpret_cast compares to Igor's "raw" cast?

Comment: @merwaaan Practically, it´s the same. It´s just that C has only this "parenthesis cast" `(type)` and C++ has three additional names for it to express what the reason for the cast is (and a really new, fourth type of cast too, but not important here)

Comment: it's almost exactly the same, but a little more explicit. It is conceptually "safer" because it does not cast away constness